# Disable SSL cert verification

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on an app and need to disable SSL verification to test locally.

In this environment the SSL certificate doesn't validate so I need to disable the verification. How does one do that on Windows Phone 7.1?

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable SSL verification on the phone - what you can do is install your test cert on your phone so that it becomes trusted.

Installing the cert is as easy as emailing the CER file to yourself and opening it.

Note: Unfortunately this only works with certs signed by a trusted authority, so you can't use self signed certs. You can find the list of trusted providers for WP8 [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14215.windows-and-windows-phone-8-ssl-root-certificate-program-member-cas.aspx) or for WP 7.5 (dev version 7.1) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521150%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: You would think it would be that easy, but it's not .. unless I create a cert for every machine and every local IP address I use. Oh well I suppose.

Comment: I created a self-signed cert specific to my dev machine, installed it, restarted the phone, and still doesn't accept it. Apparently it can't be a self-signed cert.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to caveat my answer with that. Updated.